# How to maximize cancer growth?

Tags: biology, humans, hard-science, anatomy

Given the modern knowledge of human anatomy and biology what are the things one must hypothetically do in order to maximize human colorectal cancer proliferation?

Comment: Do marketing for fast food chains.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding SE, Kairos! Please take a moment to review the [tour] and [help]. They will give you a good idea what we're about here (the making or fictional worlds & settings) as well as what sorts of questions are a good fit for the WB.SE model. As I read your query, I don't see any connexion to a fictional world (be it sci-fi, fantasy, comic book, etc) What I see is an entirely primary-world based query

Comment: @Renan yeah.  "Do more of what we already know causes colorectal cancer" is the obvious answer.  Do some research and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: This might be more profitably answered at [medicalsciences.se].  In the mean time, I disagree with the close votes.  Real world questions are on-topic and while asking the OP to say "Oh, and I'm doing this to build a fictional world" would be nice, it's a triviality so long as real-world questions *are* on-topic.  And as for being too broad... whoever cast that vote must be joking.  This question may be worthy of downvoting for lack of research, but compared to a lot of other questions we leave open, it's very specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a joke comment on the question:

> Do marketing for fast food chains.

But turns out that it's very true. Obesity and sedentarism are the classical risk factors. [Others include tabagism and alcoholism](https://www.google.com.ar/amp/s/amp.cancer.org/cancer/colon-rectal-cancer/causes-risks-prevention/risk-factors.html):

> ### Being overweight or obese
>
> If you are overweight or obese (very overweight), your risk of developing and dying from colorectal cancer is higher. Being overweight (especially having a larger waistline) raises the risk of colon and rectal cancer in both men and women, but the link seems to be stronger in men.
>
> ### Physical inactivity
>
> If you're not physically active, you have a greater chance of developing colon cancer. Being more active can help lower your risk.
>
> ### Certain types of diets
>
> A diet that's high in red meats (such as beef, pork, lamb, or liver) and processed meats (like hot dogs and some luncheon meats) raises your colorectal cancer risk.
>
> Cooking meats at very high temperatures (frying, broiling, or grilling) creates chemicals that might raise your cancer risk. It’s not clear how much this might increase your colorectal cancer risk.
>
> It’s not clear if other dietary components (for example, certain types of fats) affect colorectal cancer risk.
>
> ### Smoking
>
> People who have smoked tobacco for a long time are more likely than non-smokers to develop and die from colorectal cancer. Smoking is a well-known cause of lung cancer, but it's linked to a lot of other cancers, too. If you smoke and want to know more about quitting, see our Guide to Quitting Smoking.
>
> ### Heavy alcohol use
>
> Colorectal cancer has been linked to moderate to heavy alcohol use. Limiting alcohol use to no more than 2 drinks a day for men and 1 drink a day for women could have many health benefits, including a lower risk of many kinds of cancer.

All in all, the modern western style of life itself can be said to be a risk factor for butt cancer. If we as a society don't do anything, then the number of occurrences per year only tends to grow.

Still, if you want to do something evil to help cancer, you can get a major in marketing and get yourself hired by a fast food chain. Or you can become a polictician and make tax adjustments so that fast food becomes even cheaper than it already is, compared to nowadays. Or make something similar for booze and tobacco.

Think big. The more people your actions affect, the more evil you accomplish.

Comment: Excessive smoking and alcohol will kill person with Lung or Liver cancer before they get a chance to develop colorectal cancer. Excess weight leads to diabetes and heart disease. I suggest going with fried/charred meat :) Also, look up "onco-mouse" - it was bred to have cancer.